# JIRA: Rank one up, rank one down

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Jira has epic typed tickets and normal issues, and subtasks. Normal issues can be assigned to epics and ordered inside it. It is a visual thing only because it does not effect the dependency settings (blocks, blocked by, relates, etc...). In the view screen of an epic ticket we have the "Issues" section where we have

- Rank to top
- Rank to bottom

features for each item which is fine. But I really miss the "Rank one up" and "Rank one down" features. Using the Rank to top / bottom feature to move an issue by one in the list is a pain. I can also make the "Rank" field visible on the "Edit" view and see the associated number and edit it, but it is still very inconvenient.

Do you know any plugins, easier practices for it?

(The "Structure - The issue organizer" seems OK, but is to expensive for our setup (10-25 users, $600) just to achieve this goal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rank functionality (renamed Send To Top in a recent release) is implemented as a WebWork action (e.g. RankTop.jspa which then calls the RankAction class). To have your own action you'd need a plugin that implements a new action and uses the existing RankServiceImpl class to move an issue up or down one rank.

I don't know of any existing plugins to do this but I agree it's annoying trying to move an issue around in a backlog of more than about 40 issues

Comment: I think I will do that and post a link for it when I'm done. Thanks for the quick start!

Comment: @Notinlist - did you ever do it?

Comment: @ksl Unfortunately not. I did not get the time window for "such a nuance" and I had other pet projects at the time.